# Why are styles not getting applied on wpf controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, styles

I have developed a WPF application.

I have a one resource dictionary file in which I have written styles for the wpf controls such as button or label. I need to use this wpf application in windows form application so that I have changed the output type of wpf application to Class Library and referred it in the windows application.

It referred in the windows application with no errors and I can see the wpf xaml windows, but now the styles are not getting applied to the controls in windows application.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, your resource dictionary was referenced by your App.xaml. From memory, when you host WPF content in a Winforms app, the resource resolution process does not even look at your Application object. Therefore, you will need to import your resource dictionary into the views themselves so that your styles resolve.

Comment: is there any way to use the resource dictionary from app.xaml?

Comment: Like I said, when I last played with this, it seemed that hosting WPF in Winforms does not allow this. The resource lookup ends at the root level control and skips to the theme at that point rather than looking in your `Application` object.

Answer (score 1):

Refer that resource dictionary file (.xaml) explicitly using [MergedDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries.aspx) in your WPF Window / Page / UserControl's XAML.